# Symfony2 + Doctrine: Create Entities from specific database that is not the default

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-2.1

The [Symfony2 Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) provides information on how to create entities from existing schemas, but I haven't been able to find a way to import from another database called 'legacy' (see config.yml below) that isn't the default.

Running the following command creates YAML files only from the default database

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Soapbox/DashboardBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

If I don't provide any arguments, I receive suggestions, but not sure which ones are applicable.

```
doctrine:mapping:convert [--filter="..."] [--force] [--from-database] [--extend[="..."]] [--num-spaces[="..."]] [--namespace[="..."]] [--em[="..."]] to-type dest-path
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            legacy:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     my.host
                port:     null
                dbname:   magazines
                user:     soapbox
                password: XXXXX
                charset:  UTF8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm thinking clearly which I might not be, you have two EntityManagers, default and legacy.

As such you can use the flag --em "legacy" to get it to import from that specific database.

Comment: I've upvoted, since you're onto something here, but unfortunately I get `[InvalidArgumentException] Doctrine ORM Manager named "legacy" does not exist.`. I also tried legacy_connection as the name, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I found more info in the  [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). I was missing a configuration for a second entity manager to use the second connection, then mapped each Bundle to its Enitity Manager. Your solution works after that. Thanks